# Update-mime-database deletes .xml mime file

Tags: mime-type

I'm still very much a novice, so please let me know if this has been asked before.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04.

.ris files are plaintext files that can be imported into citation managers. I would .ris files to open in my citation manager (mendeleydesktop.desktop) instead of in a text editor.

I followed the directions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes). There we no relevant entries in my mime.types file corresponding to .ris.

I added `text/ris                   ris` to my `/etc/mime.types` file, ran `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`, and then edited `mendeleydesktop.desktop` to have a line reading `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mendeley;application/pdf;text/x-bibtex;text/ris`.

When I tried to open a .ris file, it still opened in a text editor.

So I followed the instructions to make a .xml file in `/usr/share/mime/applicaitons`. Upon running `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`, that .xml file was deleted.

What am I missing? Is it possible to make files with a `*.ris` extension open in `mendeleydesktop.desktop` by default?

My .xml file is echoed below, along with it being deleted after updating.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the XML in `/usr/share/mime/packages` instead of applications. Not sure why it works but it did for me.